# Why does df show different used values for identical data on two different partitions?

Tags: disk-usage

I've just copied across some data from one raid partition to another. When I look at the output of `df`:

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md127     1921673480 1652707240  171280736  91% /home/chris/mount/raid18t
/dev/md3       2881491232 1652719488 1082329968  61% /home/chris/mount/raid3t
```

The `Used` values are not identical (`1652707240` vs `1652719488`). However, if I do a `du -s *` in each of the directories though - I get the same values/output...

Why is there a difference in the `Used` values?

Both filesystems are ext4.

Comment: Do you have many _directories_ in that data set? Have files been added and deleted over some time? If so, the directory nodes themselves would take somewhat more space than newly created directories. This depends on the filesystem though.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "data set"?. The files should be identical - I did a `cp -a ...`.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33122/du-reports-surprising-total-size-for-same-data?rq=1 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386478/interpreting-gnu-df-command-size-results-on-linux?rq=1

Comment: Showing a list of files, file systems on both devices and du on both would be useful. It's possible that the FS under /dev/md3 takes up more metadata (or has more space reserved for it) since it has to handle more 1k blocks than that of /dev/md127.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski What are the filesystems of `/dev/md127` and `/dev/md3` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, *df* reports the `size on disk` whereas *du* reports on `actual file size`. Even in the case of files being exactly the same, does not imply that the underlying file system blocks are guaranteed to be identical.

Consider a block size of *8k* on `Disk-1` and a block size of *4k* on `Disk-2`.
File `foo` has an actual size of *11k*.

`Disk-1/foo` will take 2 blocks, which uses 2*8k=16k.

`Disk-2/foo` will take 3 blocks, which uses 3*4k=12k.

**EDIT**
Just for fun, pick a directory with lots of small files in it. run `ls -l` and total the file sizes. This is the actual size of the file. On my flavor of Linux, the file size is in column 5. So I'd do something like this:
`ls -l | awk '{ttl=ttl+$5} END {print "Total file size " ttl}'`
This will total the file sizes in the directory.
Next, list the number of sectors on the disk, with `ls -ls` and total the sectors:
`ls -ls | awk '{ttl=ttl+$1} END {print "Total sector count " ttl}'`

On my system, I checked my boot directory:
`ls -lsR /boot | awk '{if (($1+0) >0) tt_sec=tt_sec+$1; tt_byt=tt_byt+$6} END {print "Sectors " tt_sec "  Bytes " tt_byt}'`
Sectors 151,352  Bytes 153,894,246
`du -xs /boot`
151360
`df /boot`
1-K blocks: 499656
Used: 151756

Notice how all 3 numbers are different?
`ls` shows the size in bytes, by default.
`df` unless otherwise configured, reports 1K blocks
*My disk is configured with 512 byte sectors (I got that from `fdisk`)*
If I add hidden files & Directories into my ls command:
`ls -lRsa (…)`
Sectors 151,504    Bytes 154,045,696
Closer, but still off.

Let me show you, now, what is happening:
-copied for convenience-
`ls -lsRa /boot | awk '{if (($1+0) >0) tt_sec=tt_sec+$1; tt_byt=tt_byt+$6} END {print "Sectors " tt_sec "  Bytes " tt_byt}'`
Sectors 151,504    Bytes 154,045,696
`df /boot`
1-K blocks: 499656
Used: 151756
`du -xs /boot`
151360

`echo "Hi" > junk`
`ls -ls junk`
4 -rw-r--r-- ScottieH user 3  junk
Notice that this 3-byte file is using 4 sectors!

-recompute sizes-
`ls -lsRa /boot | awk '{if (($1+0) >0) tt_sec=tt_sec+$1; tt_byt=tt_byt+$6} END {print "Sectors " tt_sec "  Bytes " tt_byt}'`
Sectors 151,508    Bytes 154,045,972 <-How much did this go up?
`du -xs /boot`
151364
`df /boot`
1-K blocks: 499656
Used: 151760

** Do you see how these numbers will *NEVER* add up?**

Comment: It's clear to me that it measures something else, but my question is why does it differ? Should it not be identical?

Comment: Block size seems to be identical according to `hdparm -I /dev/... | grep Physical`

Comment: I do not know what hdparm does. I'll have to look at it. Really, you are looking for the sector size on the disk. The difference in the sizes is, in summary, the difference in the actual file size, and the size on disk.

Comment: I ran `hdparm `on my /boot drive. I get different answers between `hdparm`, f`disk` and c`fdisk`. Similar, but different..